# Django authenticate method giving me None if enter even correct username and password

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views, django-login

I am trying to login with Django authentication but I am getting `None`. I have seen many tutorials and they are doing this in the same way. But when I try, I get `None`. Registration is working fine for me and it is saving the data. The problem only occurs in login. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
#models.py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

class extendeduser(models.Model):
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from django.shortcuts import render
from Home.models import extendeduser
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate,login

def Login1(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'login.html')
    else:
        print(request.POST['un'],'**********',request.POST['pwd'])
        username = request.POST['un']
        password = request.POST['pwd']
        user = authenticate(username=username,password=password)

        print(user,'***********')
        if user is not None:
            login(request,user)
            return render(request, 'Dashboard.html')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')

def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request,'home.html')
    else:
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=request.POST['un'],password=request.POST['pwd'])
        mob = request.POST['mob1']
        euser = extendeduser(mobile=mob,user=user)
        euser.save()
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

*********************--------------------------**********************--------------
    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path,include

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('Home.urls')),
]

from django.urls import path
from Home import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('login/', views.Login1),
]
```

login.html:

```
<form class="main-css" method="post" action="/home/login/">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="user">Username</label>
<input name="un" id="user" class = "form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pawd">Password</label>
<input name="pwd" id="pawd" class="form-control">
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</div>
</form>
```

signup.html:

```
<form class="main-css" action="/home/" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="form-group">
<label for="user">Username</label>
<input name="un" id="user" class = "form-control">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="pawd">Password</label>
<input name="pwd" id="pawd" class="form-control">
</div>
    <div class="form-group">
<label for="mob">Mobile Number</label>
<input name="mob1" id="mob" class="form-control">
</div>
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<input type="submit" name="pwd"  class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
</div>
</form>
```

user Table:

```
id                                                                              password    last_login  is_superuser    username    first_name  email   is_staff    is_active   date_joined last_name
1   pbkdf2_sha256$180000$LhxdGpJYRyaT$wQm4zR8ezNX3bx/7eUtZCOyQxN3DaSYx1+0V5cTBqcQ=  null    0   Raju            0   1   2020-05-23 12:33:44.983489  
2   pbkdf2_sha256$180000$gqq2Dj7tjttr$Sg740YDl7b2X+w5PjkSiXcwegB1FyySG8XwLyAeEi3k=  null    0   Aniket          0   1   2020-05-23 12:43:42.254360  
3   pbkdf2_sha256$180000$x23eKj5IJetL$XPFXHwtmQCno8SRBiFQJUMy8021Vb7Wru/nozbNgjyI=  null    0   mithun          0   1   2020-05-23 15:59:23.346678
```

Comment: what's the `is_active` status for the User ?

Comment: Hi arjun, thanks for your reply, I have checked the user table, in is_active is 1 only